# Initialize a Priority Queue with custom comparator, which is inside a HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, priority-queue

Assume that I have a `HashMap`, where the value is of type `PriorityQueue` like:

```
HashMap<Integer, PriorityQueue<Integer>> someMap = new HashMap<>();
```

But how do I initialize this `HashMap`, if I need the `PriorityQueue` to have a custom comparator?

The actual comparator is much more complex, But for simplicity let's assume that I need the `PriorityQueue` to sort by reverse order, which I can do by:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

Where and How should I define the comparator for the value in `HashMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Comparator` which `PriorityQueue` uses internally doesn't change its type anyhow.

A `PriorityQueue<Integer>` which uses the natural ordering, or `Comparator.reverseOrder()`, or for instance `Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.reverseOrder())` (or any other Comparator) is still a `PriorityQueue<Integer>`. And you can store all these Queues in a map of type `Map<Integer,PriorityQueue<Integer>>`

You don't need to do anything special while instantiating the Map, just simply invoke the constructor `new HashMap<>()` as you did.

```java
Map<Integer, Queue<Integer>> someMap = new HashMap<>();
        
Queue<Integer> pq1 = new PriorityQueue<>();
Queue<Integer> pq2 = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
Queue<Integer> pq3 = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.reverseOrder());
        
someMap.put(1, pq1);
someMap.put(2, pq1);
someMap.put(3, pq1);
```

**Note**

- That generic type parameters like `<Integer,Queue<Integer>>` are meant to allow the compiler to verify that you're using the appropriate types. It is a compile-type mechanism for preventing problems like Heap-pollution, and it has nothing to do with how the memory would be allocated at Runtime.
- You might be interested in reading [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) to learn what are the benefits of using high-level abstractions like `Map` and `Queue`.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer in the question itself. You put the comparator inside the Priority Queue instance so.

```java
HashMap<Integer, PriorityQueue<Integer>> someMap = new HashMap<>();
PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
someMap.put(1,queue);
```

that for initialization and when you put data in your queue you can use the same queue to put data.